# UDP broadcast breaks after some time on Linux 2.6.33.9 rt

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, real-time

I have several embedded systems running Linux 2.6.33.9rt.
They communicate using udp broadcast over wifi. The communication works quite well but after a few minutes some clients stop sending packets. They still receive them, though.

I was able to reproduce the problem using the following example code. The code runs for several minutes spamming broadcast messages and then it just stops. The program is still running an responding. The udp messages just don't show up on the network anymore.

Once the program stopped sending udp the only way to get it started again is by disconnecting and reconnecting the network.

Any ideas what might cause this kind of behavior?

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {

struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr,0,sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("255.255.255.255");
addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
int num = atoi(argv[2]);

int s;
if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    perror("unable to open socket");
    exit(1);
}
static int broadcast = 1;
  if(setsockopt(s,  
             SOL_SOCKET,  
             SO_BROADCAST,  
             &broadcast,  
             sizeof(broadcast)) < 0)
  {
    perror("unable to enable broadcast");
  }


for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
  char data[1400];
  if (sendto(s, data, 1400, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
  {
      perror("send error");
      exit(1);
  }
}
close(s);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: To test, can you perhaps include some sort of counter in the data you send, so it might be possible to see if the last packet sent over "the wire" matches the one the program think it's sent. It could be some sort of buffering issue, and the `sendto` call just blocks because a buffer is full.

Comment: Have you triggered some kind of UDP flood protection on your network, routers, or the target machines?

Comment: Did you use a sniffer to monitor the outbound packets? Also as @clintp suggested. what happens if you sleep after each send?

Comment: @clintp I disabled everything that might cause problems on the router. The bug is still the same. Afaik there is no flood protection running on the machines.

Comment: @Guy I sniffed the traffic using wireshark. Sleep does not change anything either. It just reduces the throughput but the bug still exists.

Comment: Are all the clients using the same hardware? What do you do to "disconnect and reconnect the network"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding the socket to a device specific broadcast address, in my case 192.168.5.255, fixes the bug. I have no idea why this happens but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem and I can guarantee that it depends by the driver of your network card interface. Indeed, I tried with an external network card (e.g. an Alpha Card) and I didn't have this problem anymore. I hope that this suggestion can be useful for other people that will face the same issue.